# Find the hidden message in this weird array

Tags: calculation-puzzle, language, missing-digits

This puzzle is from my best friend.

```
  ? ? 0
    ? ?
  ? ? ?
1 3 0
1 8 2 0
```

Figure out the answer.
Do not ignore any of the tags!
Find out the numbers replaced by Question marks.

Answer (score 2):

I get

> ```
>    1 3 0
>      1 4
>    5 2 0
>  1 3 0
>  1 8 2 0
> ```

Because

> it looks like a multiplication problem, showing work:
>
> ```
>      1 3 0
>    x   1 4
>    -------
>      5 2 0
>  + 1 3 0
>  ---------
>    1 8 2 0
> ```
>
> So the middle line is gotten by subtracting the 4th line from the last, and then the first line must be the same as the 4th line and the second line must be 1 and then 4 $\times$ 1, or 4.

Comment: Please read the whole question, including the tags.

Comment: The language tag is supposed to come into play here.

Comment: @duck I used the "language" tag because this puzzle is from my best friend, which asks me to find a hidden sentence.

Answer (score 2):

After @SteveV's progress:

> ```
>    1 3 0
>      1 4
>    5 2 0
>  1 3 0
>  1 8 2 0
> ```

Then, given the [language](/questions/tagged/language) tag, we now

> Substitute the numbers with similar sounding **Chinese** characters.

Giving

> ```
>     一 生 0
>        一 世
>     我 愛 你
>  一 生 0
>  要 不 愛 你
> ```

Meaning (approximately)

> (lines 1-2) My whole life
>  (lines 3-4) I love you my whole life
>  (line 5) Love you or not?